# I get 'is not a function' Error when calling Factory method from controller in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to call a factory method in angular.js from my controller method and it throws an error 'is not a function'

Here's how the factory looks:

```
function getData($q) {
  var getMessages = function(id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    // deferred.notify('About to greet ' + name + '.');
    GTS2_FIN_MU_Dist_Pct_Controller.getUltimates(
      id,
      function(result, event) {
        if (event.status) {
          //      console.log(result);
          var obj = JSON.parse(result);
          deferred.resolve(obj);
        } else {
          deferred.reject("Error Processing the Request :  " + event.message);
        }
      },
      { escape: false }
    );
    return deferred.promise;
  };
  return {
    getMessages: getMessages,
  };
}

app.factory("getData", getData);
```

The controller looks like:

```
app.controller("intlMassUpdateDistPctController", function($scope) 
        { // define angular controller
        $scope.ultimates = new Array; // define empty array to hold ultimate versions from VF remote action
        // Calls controller method Remote Action and passes the ultimateId, and handles the result by storing it inside $scope.ultimateVersions
        $scope.loadData = function(){
            //$j214('#dialogNew').show();
            var promise = getData.getMessages('');  //Calling factory method.. This is where U get the error
            promise.then(function(obj) {
            $scope.selectedForecastLocked = false;
            var JSONdata = JSON.parse(obj);
            $scope.ultimates = JSONdata.Ultimates;
            $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData($scope.ultimates);
                    ........
            }, function(reason) {
                        alert('Failed: ' + reason);
                    }, function(update) {
                        alert('Got notification: ' + update);
                    });
            }
        });
```

I have also defined the app.

```
var app = angular.module('intlMassUpdateDistPct', ['agGrid','ui.bootstrap']);
```

And Finally:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" >
<div ng-controller="intlMassUpdateDistPctController">
```

Can someone please help me identify what's missing.

Comment: Didn't you forget to inject the factory to the controller (like you did with $scope)?

Comment: @PJDev Thanks so much. I can't believe I missed injecting the factory.

Comment: No problem. By the way, if I were you, I would consider using string array injection instead of plain arguments injection: `app.controller("intlMassUpdateDistPctController", ['$scope', 'getData', function($scope, getData) { ... }])`. If you ever decide to minify the JS files with your approach, everything will be broken because all arguments will be given random names. The string array approach will protect you from that ;)

Comment: @PJDev : Not so, if he is using `gulp-ng-annotate` . It can be done either ways

Answer (score 0):

Try to inject `getData` factory in the controller :

```
app.controller("intlMassUpdateDistPctController", function($scope,getData){
   // your code...
})
```